# How to configure CLion for a Doxygen-style file header?

Tags: c++, doxygen, clion

Every time I create a .cpp/.h file on CLion, I get an automatic file header like this:

```
//
// Created by me on 09/11/18.
//
```

This is neat, but I'd rather like something Doxygen-compliant like this:

```
/*!
 * @author me
 * @date 03/12/18.
 */
```

I could easily edit this and add more Doxygen-fields thanks to the nice CLion integration.

This seems a trivial task, but I still did not manage to achieve it. May someone help me out?

Regards,

Edit:
As suggested, I went to "File and Code Templates", then clicked on the "Includes" Tab (Files was selected by default) and I found the pattern I was looking for. I modified it as in the following:

```
#if ($HEADER_COMMENTS)
/*!
 * @author $USER_NAME 
 * @date ${DATE}
#if ($ORGANIZATION_NAME && $ORGANIZATION_NAME != "")
 * Copyright (c) $YEAR ${ORGANIZATION_NAME}#if (!$ORGANIZATION_NAME.endsWith(".")).#end All rights reserved.
#end
 */
#end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `File->Settings...->Editor->File and Code Templates->Includes`.
There you will find an include called `C File Header` which is included by all other C/C++ related file types and can be adjusted for your needs.

Comment: Yep! I just took too long to browse among the different tabs before I finally found the pattern I needed.