# Modify Doxygen template in CLion

Tags: doxygen, clion

In Clion when I type/** it generates a stub looking like this:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param txdata 
 * @param rxdata 
 * @param bitmask 
 * @param length 
 */
```

However I would like to extend it to have more information, at least the `@brief` notation:

```
 /**
 * @brief   A brief description, one sentence, one line.
 * @details A detailed description of the functionality, it can span over
 *          multiple lines, can be omitted.
 * @pre     Prerequisites about the use of the functionality, there can be
 *          more than one "pre" tags, can be omitted.
 * @post    Postrequisites about the use of the functionality, there can be
 *          more than one "post" tags, can be omitted.
 * @note    There can be one or more notes, can be omitted.
 *
 * @param[in] p1        description of parameter one
 * @param[out] p2       description of parameter two
 * @param[in,out] p3    description of parameter three
 * @return              Description of the returned value, must be omitted if
 *                      a function returns void.
 * @retval VALUE1       description of the special returned value one, can be
 *                      omitted.
 * @retval VALUE2       description of the special returned value two, can be
 *                      omitted.
 *
 * @api|@notapi|@special|@init|@sclass|@iclass|@xclass|@isr
*/
```

Is there any, way to add more tags to the doxygen generator in Clion? Couldn't find anything in the settings.

I'm using Clion 2020.1

Comment: I don't use CLion but did you have a look at the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596489/how-to-configure-clion-for-a-doxygen-style-file-header

Comment: Already found that, different thing though :) That's about the template for a file, not a code snippet

Comment: As said I don't use CLion, but the page: https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/features/code-documentation.html suggests that empty  `@brief`` and  `@return` should be present (at least for `///` comments. So there might be a "template" somewhere in the "settings".

Comment: Yup, thats what I'm not able to find :)

Comment: There is the issue on JetBrains site about configuring doxygen template https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6835